# Convert NSString to NSDictionary separated by specific character

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdictionary

I need to convert this "5?8?519223cef9cee4df999436c5e8f3e96a?EVAL_TIME?60?2013-03-21" string into dictionary. Separated by "?"

Dictionary would be some thing like

```
{
    sometext1 = "5",
    sometext2 = "8",
    sometext3 = "519223cef9cee4df999436c5e8f3e96a",
    sometext4 = "EVAL_TIME",
    sometext5 = "60",
    sometext6 = "2013-03-21"
}
```

Thank you .

Comment: If any of below answer helps you please accept one , so the others can easily found the solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Break the string to smaller strings and loop for them.
This is the way

```
NSArray *objects = [inputString componentsSeparatedByString:@"?"];
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
int i = 1;
for (NSString *str in objects)
{
    [dict setObject:str forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"sometext%d", i++]];
}
```

Comment: your logic goes fine, but you had 4-5 syntax errors!!  I corrected those.

Comment: Thank you but keys has to be different . Any thing like xyz , abc , etc sometext1,2,3 is just for giving you an idea .

Comment: @MuhammadSaadAnsari: from where are you getting those keys?

Comment: { cid = "5", avid = "8", sid = "519223cef9cee4df999436c5e8f3e96a", TLicense  = "EVAL_TIME", LLicense  = "60", date = "2013-03-21" } . This is how i want this dictionary. These keys are generating from my self only for future use but that string i am geting from server.

Comment: I got the answer by myself . Thank you all of you. :) 

This is what i am doing

    NSString *testString = @"5?8?519223cef9cee4df999436c5e8f3e96a?EVAL_TIME?60?2013-03-21";
    NSArray *list = [testString componentsSeparatedByString:@"?"];
    NSLog(@"Count %d",[list count]);
    NSLog(@"Dictionary %@", [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:list forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"cid",@"avid",@"sid",@"tlicense",@"llicense",@"date", nil]]);

Comment: @MuhammadSaadAnsari That would work fine as long as the inputString is proper.

Comment: I didn't write in xCode, but in the browser, and from my iPhone. That's why I had syntax errors...sorry!

Comment: Hi, how can i separate two values from NSDictionary am getting response like this { "Result" : "Select~, CUSTDAM~CUSTOMER DAMAGE, PM~PREVENTATIVE MAINTENANCE, WEAR~WEAR AND TEAR" } -  How do i separate Values before the ~ symbol ex - Select,CUSTDAM,PM,WEAR

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
NSString *string = @"5?8?3519223cef9cee4df999436c5e8f3e96a?EVAL_TIME?60?2013-03-21";

NSArray *stringComponents = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"?"];
//This is very risky, your code is at the mercy of the input string
NSArray *keys = @[@"cid",@"avid",@"sid",@"TLicense",@"LLicense",@"date"];

NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (int idx = 0; idx<[stringComponents count]; idx++) {
    NSString *value = stringComponents[idx];
    NSString *key = keys[idx];
    [dictionary setObject:value forKey:key];
}
```

EDIT: More optimized

```
NSString *string = @"5?8?3519223cef9cee4df999436c5e8f3e96a?EVAL_TIME?60?2013-03-21";

NSArray *stringComponents = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"?"];
NSArray *keys = @[@"cid",@"avid",@"sid",@"TLicense",@"LLicense",@"date"];

NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:stringComponents forKeys:keys];
```

Comment: @HAS Thanks for your kind words.

Answer (score 0):

first separate the string into several arrays by '?'.

then add the string in you dictionary.

sth like this:

```
NSString *str = @"5?8?519223cef9cee4df999436c5e8f3e96a?EVAL_TIME?60?2013-03-21";
NSArray *valueArray = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"?"];
NSMutableArray *keyArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i <[valueArray count]; i ++) {
    [keyArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"sometext%d",i+1]];
}
NSDictionary *dic = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:valueArray forKeys:keyArray];
```

Answer (score 0):

For the future: If you were to store your data in JSON format (closer to what you have anyway), it'll be much easier to deal with and transfer between systems. You can easily read it...using NSJSONSerialization